# Why Razor doesnt render part of partial view

Tags: c#, razor

i have code in partial view like this:

```
@model Parameters

@{
    int i = 0;
    int a = i;
}

TestTestTest

@Html.TextBox("Test");

<input type="submit" value="@Parameters.Text" />
```

I can see that code in @{} runs properly, but razor doesn't render my textbox and button. why? what to do?

Comment: how you are calling the view?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, i write @Html.Partial("_name_of_partial_view")

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, i tried to make another project, i did the same as in this project, of course everything works fine in that project, but not in this. And i have no idea why.

Comment: for sure there is something that is missing in this project which is there in another project